# Applying formatting from Access database to a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ms-access-2007

Perhaps this is mere wishful thinking, but is there a simple way (in ASP.NET) to extract (at run-time) the formatting for different columns from a table in an Access 2007 database and apply that formatting to a GridView control?

Also, is there a way to get the "Caption" values for columns in a table in the database and use those as the column headers for the GridView?

I'm new at ASP.NET, so I don't know what's possible and what isn't :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is wishful thinking.  The drivers for ADO.NET to Access don't give you style information.

Comment: With DAO (instead of ADO.NET) you should be able to get all the properties of the fields. That means using COM, which may be unacceptable, but it's a way to get the job done.